# Why is CodeBlocks not working?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I will be learning C for a class this summer and I'm trying to get CodeBlocks working on my Linux Mint 17 machine. So I've watched some YouTube videos on how to do it and all they do is install CodeBlocks, create a new project, put console application, click on the default main.c program that's provided to you by the program and hit build and run, which is exactly what I did except in the build message I get:

```
fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory?
```

What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Can't _quite_ see your screen or hard-disk contents from here, a precise answer is not possible with the supplied information. So... what happens if you go to the console and type `locate stdio.h` and, if that fails, if you then type `sudo updatedb`, followed by the `locate stdio.h` cmd?

Comment: if i type locate stdio.h it says two things one is /usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/CORE/nostdio.h and the other thing it says would be /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500018/unable-to-compile-simple-c-program-in-linux-mint-15

Comment: Hmmm. They're both the same results I get when looking for the file in Mint r16 x64. (a system that currently does _not_ have C::B installed in it). On another machine (mint r13 x64) which _does_ have C::B installed, I also get: `/usr/include/stdio.h`, `/usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/stdio.h` and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h`. Never had the problem you describe - I've downloaded + installed C::B from the Package Manager, Software Manager and the command-line. I'd try removing and re-installing C::B if I was in your shoes. (Not sure if it would help though)

Comment: Try making sure you have a complete compiler toolchain installed: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install package libc6-dev:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`