# geany: C++ Including libraries and headers

Tags: c++, ubuntu, geany

I'm very new in Ubuntu and programming C++ on Ubuntu using Geany.
The problem I have here is that:
the classes i want to iclude to my project will receive an error,
I type,

```
#include <vector>
```

the error given here is,

> fatal error: vector: No such file or directory

also I cannot use namespace std,
typing `using namespace std` returns the following error,

> error: unknown type name 'using'

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> //no problem here
#include "stdlib.h" //no problem here
#include <vector> //this is a problem (lets say it returns error 1)
using namespace std; //this is a problem (lets say it returns error 2)
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can advise.

Comment: I don't even know what geany is, but that one line of code you posted is a perfectly fine line of C++ code.  So the problem is something beyond that.  Probably something with your compiler environment.  Either post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or start talking about your environment.

Comment: Simillar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500018/unable-to-compile-simple-c-program-in-linux-mint-15

Comment: Have you saved you file as .c/.C instead of .cpp? If a, rename it or manual change to C++ via Document->Set Filetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you are using the wrong compiler to compile your C++ code. For example, by invoking `gcc test.cpp` the C++ file is actually compiled as C and you receive errors such as the one you posted - there is no `vector` header in C and there is also no `using` keyword.

If you are using `gcc`, the correct way to invoke the compiler to compile C++ is via the `g++` symlink, i.e. `g++ test.cpp`

If you are using clang, the executable is called `clang++` instead.

Both compilers support the `-x` parameter to manually change the language to C++, although in that case you also have to specify that the compiler needs to link your files with the C++ standard library. For example: `gcc -x c++ test.cpp -lstdc++`

Comment: Geany is detecting the filetype by file's extension. So if the file is called .c oder .C it might reconized it as plain C file. To fix this, rename it to .cpp (I guess it's the default) or manual change filetype to change between preconfigured g++/gcc usage.