# Header files are not found by GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, include-path, c-standard-library

Working with embedded C-projects. There are libraries, include files and so on - for micro controllers. No need for me to use GCC for a host machine and OS (Linux Mint 64 bit). As a rule...

But now I'm trying to compile [mspdebug](https://github.com/dlbeer/mspdebug) project from a Github - with a GCC of course. And I get an error at the very begin of make:

```
mspdebug$ make
cc  -DUSE_READLINE  -O1 -Wall -Wno-char-subscripts -ggdb -I. -Isimio -Iformats -Itransport -Idrivers -Iutil -Iui -DLIB_DIR=\"/usr/local/lib/\"  -o util/btree.o -c util/btree.c
util/btree.c:19:20: fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assert.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I search for the includes in all possible paths (I've got the list of them via gcc -v command) - there are no assert.h file, as well, as stdio.h and so on. Except virtual box directories there is only one place (where GCC does not search includes): /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include

AFAIK, all standard libs and includes are installed with the GCC. So I try to reinstall GCC (4.8.4) - nothing changes.

What is the normal way to give GCC all standard environment it needs?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the right direction set by [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) I found the info [in the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500018/unable-to-compile-simple-c-program-in-linux-mint-15). So I did the following:

1) installed build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

2) installed libusb (since my try to build the package revealed the absence of usb.h):

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

And it is OK! The mspdebug (v.023) is compiled and successfully tested!

So, Linux Mint 17.2 (at least) requires installing some libs to a GCC, the most basic is build-essential.

Answer (score 3):

`assert.h` is not part of `gcc`, it's a part of `glibc`.

Most likely, your Linux distribution puts the system headers into a separate package that you need to install.

Fedora, for examples, puts the header files in the `glibc-headers` package. However, you can't be using Fedora, because Fedora's `gcc` package has a dependency on `glibc-headers`, to make sure that it gets pulled in.

Whatever Linux distribution you're using, you need to research which distribution package will install the system header files you need to build stuff with.

Comment: Sam, I use Linux Mint 17.2. OK, will search that package. Just was puzzled with the very possibility of separate installing of GCC and standard libs.

I will report the result. Thank you!

Comment: I was having this issue on Fedora and had to change -target i386-linux-none to -target i386-linux-gnu